How to ignore the WPF global styles for elements which are not created from the same application thread?
We have an SDK which has many WPF views/components and logic that we deliver to our customers, and then on top of that they have their own WPF views etc.
Our UI elements are created and managed by our own UI thread, which has its own dispatcher.
Our thread is initialized something like below:
_feedbackThread = new Thread(FeedbackThread)
{
    // Name all SDK threads for debug output
    Name = "FeedbackUiThread",
    IsBackground = true
};
_feedbackThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
_feedbackThread.Start();

and the FeedbackThread method looks like:
private void FeedbackThread()
{
   // create UI window etc
   //.....

   Dispatcher.Run();
}

When they apply shared global styles, an exception occurs (InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. ).
For example, when they add a global style for StackPanel element, the style object is created once the application starts, and then at a later point on a button click they will execute the initialization code of our SDK, and open a new window from it, hence the StackPanel object from the SDK window will try to reuse the same shared style objects created globally, and it fails because these objects are created from a different thread.
One solution to this problem is to edit our StackPanel objects to set the style to NULL or a similar approach, but this is costly to identify all UI elements that need to have this style set to NULL, and secondly it's hard to not forget in the future to apply the same trick on the new UI elements.
Using <Window.Resources> to create an empty style helps, but then I would have to set an empty style for every element type there is, which is still not optimal.
Is there any better solution to this problem?
A simple repo to check the issue can be found here
